# PHP/ Markdown: Need to match code blocks inside backticks

Tags: php, markdown, preg-match-all

I am creating a developers site with code views,
but when they type code i need to it a certain way so in the php and can convert it to html a special way,

The markdown i need to be able to work with is

````
```codechanger
``php
<?php ?>
``
``c#
$foo = bar;
``
```
````

So once the first regex select code changer I then need to be able to select each code but i just need to know the regex to match everything inside there even if it is on multiple lines.

This is what i was trying to use

```
preg_match_all("/\`\`codechanger.*?^\`\`[^\r\n]*/s", $text, $out);
```

Any questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the text between a start and end point, you can do something like this:  `START .*?  END`

````
```codechanger(.*?)```
````

When combined with the `s` flag like you have, that will give you everything in `$1` between the starting and ending positions.

Once you have the results you can do another `preg_match_all` to get the inner tags.

[Here is a demo](http://ideone.com/HFFA4m)